# Exactly one occurence of value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find a native php function which returns `true` if there is exactly one occurrence of any given element in an array.

For example:

```
$searchedForValue = 3;

$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$array2 = [1,2,3,3,4,5];
$array3 = [1,2,4,5,6];

oneOccurrence($array1,$searchedForValue);
oneOccurrence($array2,$searchedForValue);
oneOccurrence($array3,$searchedForValue);
```

This should return:

```
true
false
false
```

Cheers

Comment: `$valueCount = array_count_values($array); if (isset($valueCount[$searchedForValue]) && ($valueCount[$searchedForValue] == 1)) { ... }`

Comment: echo doesn't need brackets in php.

Comment: your `word` and `expected result` is not matching

Comment: Note  that all answers using `array_count_values` require your search and array values to be *cast-able* to something that is a proper array key. That's might not always be the case (e.g. resources and similar), you'll need to judge if that's good enough for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) here.

```
$array_values = array_count_values($array2);
```

This will return an array. Key denotes each element of `$array2` and value denotes frequency of each element.:

```
Array ( 
  [1] => 1 
  [2] => 1 
  [3] => 2  // Denotes 3 appears 2 times
  [4] => 1 
  [5] => 1 
)

if (@$array_values[$searchedForValue] == 1) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

Comment: if I'd use this with `$array3`, php would complain about an undefined index, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes but it will return false since there's no 3 present in `$array3`. Howevery, you could add a `@` sign in front of the function to avoid that undefined index message.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want. Bare in mind, `echo`ing `oneOccurence` won't output 'true' or 'false', it returns a boolean.

```
function oneOccurrence ($arr, $val) {
    $occurrences = [];
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if ($v == $val) {
            $occurrences[] = $v;
        }
    }

    return count($occurrences) == 1;
}
```

P.S `echo` doesn't need brackets as it's a PHP construct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching for **one** occurrence: http://codepad.org/cZImb4FI

Use  **array_count_values()**

```
<?php

$searchedForValue = 3;

$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,3,4,5);
$array3 = array(1,2,4,5,6);

$arr = array($array1,$array2 ,$array3);

function array_count_values_of($value, $array) {
    $counts = array_count_values($array);
    return $counts[$value];
}

foreach($arr as $ar){
if( array_count_values_of($searchedForValue,$ar)==1){echo "true";}else{echo "false";}
}

?>
```

**output**

**true false false**

Answer (score 0):

A small utility function - count array values using [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) and then if the search key exists and if its count is exactly 1, return `true` otherwise `false`:

```
function oneOccurrence($array, $searchValue) {
    $array = array_count_values($array);
    return (array_key_exists($searchValue, $array) && $array[$searchValue]==1)?true:false;
}
```

Check [EVAL](https://eval.in/719860)

Answer (score -1):

```
    //In Php in_array() function is provided..

    $searchedForValue = 3;

$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,3,4,5);
$array3 = array(1,2,4,5,6);

if(in_array($searchedForValue,$array1))
{
    echo "true";
}
else 
{
    echo "false";
}

if(in_array($searchedForValue,$array2))
{
    echo "true";
}
else 
{
    echo "false";
}

if(in_array($searchedForValue,$array3))
{
    echo "true";
}
else 
{
    echo "false";
}
```